# Erro PDO Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

Tags: pdo

Please Help me, i have error in my script.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty' in C:\xampp\htdocs\File\project\blog\class\Blog.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\File\project\blog\class\Blog.php(36): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\File\project\blog\index.php(32): Blog->dataview(NULL) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\File\project\blog\class\Blog.php on line 36

```
    public function dataview($query) 
{
    $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;


    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php print($row['judul']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php print($row['kategori']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php print($row['isi']); ?></td>
                    <td><a href="#"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="#"></a></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>

            <tr>
                <td>Not Found</td>
            </tr>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SQL query is not getting passed to execute, there are errors in your $query.

Comment: problem is clear... : ->dataview(NULL) ... this is the point! just check for null value passed and handle it..